# Which URL to use for Websocket server on an EC2 instance behind ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-websocket

I am running a spring boot application on an EC2 instance behind an ELB. The application has a chatroom using websocket and both the client code(JS) as well as websocket server code(Spring) are running on the EC2.

When running the application on my own computer I was able to use localhost/5000 on the JS code to connect to the websocket server. I changed the websocket URL to the ip address of the EC2 instance with the 5000 port after. (ws://**.**.***.***:5000) However, I am getting this error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at joined (eval at xhr.onload
```

which then turns into this

```
 failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

is this the right URL to be using? (The IP address of the ec2 instance)

Answer (score 0):

Worked after getting rid of the 5000 port after ec2 ip address.